# Is there a way to create a view or select a record from only one of the two tables which have slightly different columns using union and when exists

Tags: sql

Is there a way to create a view or
select a record from only one of the two tables which have slightly different columns using union and when exists or any other simpler way?

I am trying to do it in one query if possible rather than running two separate queries.

For example there is standard and exception/override table:

```
`select
   override_salary_num as overrideSalaryNumber
   effective_start_dte as effectiveStartDate,
   effective_end_dte as effectiveEndDate,
   employee_Id as employeeId,
   null as employeeRole,
   null as employeeRoleType,
   bonus_rate as bonusRate,
   base_salary as baseSalary,
   merit_increase_Rate as meritRate       
from
  employee_salary_override a
  WHERE a.employee_Id in (1) 
and a.effective_start_dte  <= '2023-12-01' 
and a.effective_end_dte>='2023-12-01'
UNION 
select
   standard_salary_num as standardSalaryNumber,
   effective_start_dte as effectiveStartDate,
   effective_end_dte as effectiveEndDate,
   null as employeeId,
   b.employee_Role_Number as employeeRole,
   1 as employeeRoleType,
   bonus_rate as bonusRate,
   base_salary as baseSalary,
   merit_increase_Rate as meritRate
from
   employee_standard_salary b
where b.employee_Role_Number=5
AND b.effective_start_dte <= '2023-12-01'
AND b.effective_end_dte >= '2023-12-01'
AND NOT EXISTS  
(select * from employee_salary_override c
where a.employee_Id in (1) 
and a.effective_start_dte  <= '2023-12-01' 
and a.effective_end_dte>='2023-12-01'
);`
```

Currently using two separate queries, looking to derive a single query that works without performance compromise. There is nothing common between the two tables except for the start and end dates, which is making it tricky to use union all`

Comment: without knowing the tables involved, it can not be researched, also it and when you get an error fix it

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.